# Firebird Configuration: firebird.conf Parameters Unit of Measurement

Tags: configuration, firebird

Many of the parameters in the firebird.conf configuration file are integers and I'm unsure what unit of measurement (KB, Byte etc.) is being used. For example, if tweaking the TempCacheLimit param, is the value in kilobytes or bytes (or a different unit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `firebird.conf` is extensively documented in the file itself, and explicitly explains this, as an example, in Firebird 3:

> ```
> # Please note, by default a number of the values are specified in **Bytes** (Not KB).
> # You may add obvious abbreviations k, m and g in the end of a number to specify
> # kilobytes, megabytes and gigabytes.
> ```

The support for `k`, `m`, `g` is new in Firebird 3, previous versions provided a conversion table.

And for values that expect a different unit, this is documented, for example:

> ```
> # Maximum summary size of each user trace session's log files in MB.
> ```

Some values that expect bytes, repeat this in their specific documentation (but not all).

Not all numeric values are sizes in bytes, some represent a number of data pages, port numbers, seconds, booleans, or percentages. For each of these the unit is documented.

Answer (score 1):

[LowlyDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/45616/lowlydba) pointed out that the [official documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/config-fb-conf.html) makes it clear that the integer based parameters are **measured in bytes**.